# Compounding a binomial distribution where the number of observation is binomial?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am looking for a definition of a binomial distribution where the number of observation is itself binomial. That is: $X \sim binom(N, q)$ When $N \sim binom(n, p)$.

Is this a known distribution? And how can I find its probability function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say $N$ is Binomial$(n,p)$, and given $N$, $X$ is Binomial$(N,q)$.  You can get $N$ by flipping $n$ independent $p$-coins and counting the number of heads; so $X$ corresponds to flipping an additional $q$-coin for each of the original heads, and counting the number of double heads.

This implies that $X$ is Binomial$(n,pq)$.

We can check this by using the formula for the [probability generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) for the binomial twice:
$$ \mathbb{E}[a^X|N] = \sum_{k=1}^N {N \choose k} q^k (1-q)^{N-k} a^k = (1+aq-q)^N $$
and so
$$ \mathbb{E}[a^X] = (1+(1+aq-q)p-p)^n = (1+apq-pq)^n ,$$
which matches the moment generating function for the Binomial$(n,pq)$.

Comment: In other words: for each of $n$ trials, you're counting a success if the $q$-coin and $p$-coin both ame up heads, which is just a fancy way of flipping a $$pq$-coin.

Comment: This is the pgf you are computing ---> not the mgf.

Comment: oh yeah.... +1... time to delete my own answer...

Comment: Thank you Petrelharp. I understood the reasoning, but not the formulation. Could you expand on them a bit (and/or give more links) - to help me better get how you've done it? Thanks.

Comment: @wolfies good point, oops.  edited to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

A way to find its probability function is:

$P\left\{ X=k\right\} =\mathbb{E}\left(\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}\right)$ where $n\sim\text{Bin}\left(N,p_{n}\right)$.

(Here $\binom{n}{k}:=0$ if $n<k$.)

This because:

$P\left\{ X=k\mid n\right\} =\binom{n}{k}p^{k}q^{n-k}$ if $k\leq n$ (and $0$ otherwise).

I am not familiar with the distribution.